# Infimum $\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n} $

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I need to find infimum $\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}$. Candidate is $ 0$. The first part of infimum definition is clear. I don't understand how to find $N(\varepsilon)$:
$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}<\varepsilon+0$$
Maybe I can make some upper estimate but my attempts here were not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove by induction that for $n$ large enough (say $n>10$), you have $2^n>(n+1)^3$, then write

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}<\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$$

if $n>\max\left\{1+\frac{1}{\epsilon},10\right\}$

$\\$

EDIT: Details of the proof by induction of $2^n>(n+1)^3$

Base Case: For $n=11$ we have $2048>1728$ which is true.

Induction step: If $2^{n-1}>n^3$ then $2^n=2\cdot 2^{n-1}>2n^3>(n+1)^3$

The last inequality is equivalent to $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3<2$ which is equivalent to $n>\frac{1}{\sqrt[3] 2-1}\approx 3.84$, which is obviously true when $n>10$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Suppose that you knew that $(n+1)^2<2^{n/2}$; then you’d have

$$\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}<\frac{2^{n/2}}{2^n}=\frac1{2^{n/2}}\;,$$

and $\frac1{2^{n/2}}$ can certainly be made as small as you like.

Of course $(n+1)^2$ *isn’t* less than $2^{n/2}=\left(\sqrt2\right)^n$ when $n$ is fairly small, but you know that an exponential with a base greater than $1$ grows faster than any polynomial, so you know that $(n+1)^2<2^{n/2}$ for all sufficiently large $n$. To finish the argument, you just have to work out what *sufficiently large* is in this case. And you don’t have to hit the nail right on the head. For instance, you might note that $21^2=441<1024=2^{10}$, so that $(n+1)^2<2^{n/2}$ when $n=20$. Now show by induction on $n$ that $(n+1)^2<2^{n/2}$ for all $n\ge 20$.

Answer (score 1):

[An alternative to the $\epsilon-N$ approach] The function $f(x)=\frac{(x+1)^2}{2^x}$ has limit $0$ when $x\to+\infty$;
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)^2}{2^x}\overset{L'H}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2(x+1)}{\log (2)2^x}\overset{L'H}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}{\log(2)^22^x}=0.
$$

Comment: Is it okay to use lim when I try to say something about inf?

Comment: It depends. Notice that the existence of the limit is given by L'Hopital's rule (applied twice). This obviously have sense to $f(x)$. The reason why this approach work here is because your sequence is positive and converges to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ (so its infimum "is attained at $\infty$"). For other cases one may not find a suitable function $f(x)$, or the limit may not exist, or the infimum may be attained at a finite value,...